# After login from facebook, new fragmetActivty is not opned

Tags: android

I am working with facebook integration with my app. After successful login, i am starting a class which extends a fragmentActivity but it is showing error- this error- "11-26 11:40:13.281: E/AndroidRuntime(2489): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: netleon.sansar.kent.Prespetive"

```
@Override
public void onComplete(Bundle values) {

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrfs.edit();
    editor.putString("access_token", facebook.getAccessToken());
    editor.putLong("access_expires", facebook.getAccessExpires());
    editor.commit();

    Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Perspective.class);
    context.startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: have you define this activity in AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: Yes, already addded them but the problem is the class extending fragmentActivity is not starting through intent.

Comment: When tried to open class extended Activity its working fine but when i change it to FragmentActivity it not working.

Comment: No it's not create any problem.

Comment: Thanks to all, I resolve my problem. The mistake was that my jar file are not properly imported. As i do this, its work.

Comment: Okay good luck and post your comment as ans which may help other have same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolve my problem. The mistake was that my jar file are not properly imported. As i do this, its work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
   Intent i = new Intent(YourActivityName.this, Perspective.class);
   YourActivityName.this.startActivity(i);
```

instead of

```
   Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Perspective.class);
   context.startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

You missing to define Perspective activity in AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<activity android:name=".Perspective"/>
```